# Mocha websocket tests do not fail/pass reliably

Tags: express, websocket, bdd, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write some simple tests with Mocha for a websocket demo. I've been getting really inconsistent results. I have:

```
var socketURL = `http://0.0.0.0:8888`;
var options ={
  transports: ['websocket'], 'force new connection': true
};

describe("Login functions: ", function(){
    describe("tracks numbers correctly", function(){
        it('Adds users correctly:', function(){
            var bar = io.connect(socketURL, options);
            bar.on('joined', function(m){
                expect(m).to.have.length(10)
                bar.disconnect()
            })
        })
    })

    describe("adding guests", function(){
        it('New users should be guests', function(){
            var foo = io.connect(socketURL, options);
            foo.on('joined', function(members){
                expect(members).to.include('aaa')
                foo.disconnect()
            })
        });
    })
})
```

Both tests should fail. If I run them on a freshly started instance of the node server, they both pass. If I run them a few more times the first eventually fails.

I've tried a few different ways of coding this, and a couple of assertion libraries (first should.js, then chai's should(), now chai's expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `done`, like this:

```
   it('Adds users correctly:', function(done){
        var bar = io.connect(socketURL, options);
        bar.on('joined', function(m){
            expect(m).to.have.length(10)
            bar.disconnect()
            done()
        })
    })
```

When you have `done` as a parameter, the test doesn't end until you call `done()`. This is important when you use asynchronous callbacks. You can't guarantee when they're called, so right now it's possible that Mocha thinks the test is done, even though the callback hasn't actually finished.

The test may still fail, but it should do it consistently, unless it has some dependency that isn't consistent.

See also: http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/

Comment: Thanks. I'd been using the done() callback previously, but removed it at some point. Adding it back in got them to fail correctly.